# Use of SpEL in context configuration

Tags: spring, configuration-files, spring-el

I am trying to conditionally import a bean configuration file based on the value of the protocol component `<em>url</em>` property, specifically, for the `HTTPS` `URL` I would like to import `ws-https.xml` file, otherwise I'd like to import `ws-http.xtml` file. I thought the following `SpEL` expression, which does not work:

```
<import resource="'ws-' + #{'${url}'.startsWith('https') ? 'https' : 'http'} + '.xml'" />
```

What am I doing wrong and how can my objective be realised? TIA.

Comment: Where is the 'url' property coming from. Placeholders in import statements are only resolved for system and environment properties not properties file loaded afterwards. Also your placeholder is between quotes which makes it a literal `String` if I recall.

Comment: The property is resolved correctly. Thanks for pointing out the quotes issue. Unfortunately, it did not help. I had edited the import element to   <import resource="ws-#{${url}.startsWith('https') ? 'https' : 'http'}.xml" /> and I see in the log that the El is not evaluated but used literally: Imported 0 bean definitions from relative location [ws-#{https://www.ps.com:8443/aa/services/aa.startsWith('https') ? 'https' : 'http'}.xml]